# Pipes between child processes in C

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

I've seen this question before, but still a bit confused: how would I create communication between child processes of the same parent? All I'm trying to do at the moment is passing a message from the first child process to the nth child process. My idea is to create n-1 pipes in the parent process and then redirect the parent's ends to the next child process.  What I can't figure out is, how would we redirect the ends from the parent if the next child process hasn't been created? I feel there's an issue in the way I'm approaching this.

EDIT: My goal is to print the message that was passed from the first child process to the last one. It's a simple program.

Comment: IMHO, you should describe your end goal. That will help ppl suggest solutions.

Comment: is this a homework or a real problem? The answer depends on that. For real problems you should consider a different approach for IPC, as proposed in answers.

Comment: Are the child processes different programs than the parent? That is, will the child processes perform an `exec` after the fork? And, do you need the pipes to be connected to the standard file descriptors (0 for input, 1 for output, 2 for error output)?

Comment: This just a simple exercise on pipes; don't have much experience with them. So basically I have a string in the program that I want to pass only through child processes. In the end, the last child process will print the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create the processes first. The solution is as follows: you first create all the needed pipes, save them in some array. Then you do a `fork`, redirect input and output streams (for the child process) accordingly, **close unused pipe ends** and perform an `exec`. Pipes can exist without the corresponding processes, they have buffers, so you can write to a pipe while nobody's still reading, it will be ok.

You should just be aware of closing unused id's before doing `exec`. And be careful writing to a pipe which input endpoints (all the input endpoints) could become closed: it could result in a `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: How would I redirect the read() and write() ends of a pipe from a parent process to those of a child process.

Comment: `pipe` function returns a pair of file descriptors, right? By 'returns' I mean 'writes into a specified array' as in `int fds[2]; pipe( fds );`. `write` and `read` accepts file descriptors as their arguments, so you can `read( fds[0], .... )` and/or `write(fds[1], ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The code to setup a pipe and have stadin/stdout redirected to the pipe is.

In parent (before fork)

```
   int p[2];
   pipe(p);
```

In the child (after fork) to get the pipe as stdin

```
   close(0);
   dup(p[0]);
```

In the child (after fork) to get the pipe as stdout

```
  close(1);
  dup(p[1]);
```

You can start writing to the pipe as soon as it is created.  However this child process which is writing to the pipe will pause as soon as the pipe-buffer is filled and until the other process is starting reading from the pipe.

**Also look** at the **[popen call](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)**  as that may actually be a simpler version of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using un-named pipes, you may want to look into an alternate mechanism for inter-process communication such as using a FIFO, message-queue, or a socket using datagrams (i.e., UDP) that would allow you to write a "message" into the communication buffer, and then have another child read the message, see if it's for them and if it's not, have them place it back in the communicatons buffer for another child to read.  Otherwise if the message is for them, they then accept it.

Your message can be a `struct` that contains a sender ID, receiver ID, and then some buffer to hold a message, whether that's a string-type, etc.

The communications buffer can be setup by the parent, and inherited by the children.

Answer (score 0):

In a simplified non-`exec` case, you should do something like.

```
#define nproc 17

int pipes[nproc - 1][2];
int pids[nproc];

int i;
for( i = 0; i < nproc - 1; i++ ) {
    pipe( pipes[i] );
}

int rank;
for( rank = 0; rank < nproc; rank++ ) {
    pids[rank] = fork();
    if( !pids[rank] ) {
        if( rank == 0 ) {
            write( pipe[rank][1], /* your message */ );
        }

        read( pipe[rank-1][0], /* read the message somewhere*/ );

        if( rank < nproc - 1 ) {
            write( pipe[rank][1], /* write the message to the next child process*/ );
        } else {
            // Here print the received message (it's already received above)
        }
    }
}

for( rank = 0; rank < nproc; ++rank ) {
    wait( pids[rank] );
}
```

Comment: I know its been a while but I have a similar exercise although I have to use exec. Do I need to close all of the descriptors except the 2 I want to use after each fork?

Comment: You can try both ways and see what happens :)