# execlp multiple "programs"

Tags: c++, bash, command, pipe, os.execl

I want to run something like

```
cat file.tar | base64 | myprogram -c "| base64 -d | tar -zvt "
```

I use `execlp` to run the process.

When i try to run something like `cat` it works, but if i  try to run  `base64 -d | tar -zvt` it doesn't work.

I looked at the bash commands and I found out that I can run bash and tell him to run other programs. So it's something like:

```
execlp ("bash", "-c", "base64 -d | tar -zvt", NULL);
```

If I run it on the terminal, it works well, but using the `execlp` it dont work.
If I use `execlp("cat", "cat", NULL)` it works.

Someone knows how to use the `-c` param on execlp to execute multiple "programs"?
I cant use system because i use pipe and fork.

Now i noticed, if i try to use execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "base64", NULL)... nothing happens.
If i use execlp("cat", NULL) it's ok..
I'm writing to the stdin... i don't know if its the problem with the bash -c base64.. because if i run on the terminal echo "asd" | bash -c "cat"
it goes well

Comment: I have shown [in a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281894/how-do-i-chain-stdout-in-one-child-process-to-stdin-in-another-child-in-c/7282296#7282296) how you can chain an arbitrary number of processes with pipes. Hope that helps.

Comment: i thought about that, bit i'm trying to solve it with the bash, if i cant do that i will try the multiple pipe way :(... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first "argument" is what becomes `argv[0]`, so you should call with something like:

```
execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "base64 -d | tar -zvt", NULL);
```

**Edit** A small explanation what the above function does: The [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family of functions executes a program. In the above call the program in question is "bash" (first argument). Bash, like all other programs, have a `main` function that is the starting point of the program. And like all other `main` functions, the one in Bash receives two arguments, commonly called `argc` and `argv`. `argv` is an array of zero-terminated strings, and `argc` is the number of entries in the `argv` array. `argc` will always be at least 1, meaning that there is always one entry at `argv[0]`. This first entry is the "name" of the program, most often the path of the program file. All other program arguments on the command line is put into `argv[1]` to `argv[argc - 1]`.

What `execlp` does is use the first argument to find the program to be executed, and all the other arguments will be put into the programs `argv` array in the order they are given. This means that the above call to `execlp` will call the program "bash" and set the `argv` array of Bash to this:

```
argv[0] = "bash"
argv[1] = "-c"
argv[2] = "base64 -d | tar -zvt"
```

Also, `argc` of Bash will be set to 3.

If the second `"bash"` is changed to `"foo"`, then `argv[0]` of Bash will be set to `"foo"` as well.

I hope this clears it up a little bit.

Comment: why i need to call the bash 2 times?

Comment: @user1109847 You only call bash once, but you must include the zero argument to the `main()` function of bash.

Comment: i use the bash to call the bash again?

Comment: @user1109847 In your own program, the `main` function has two arguments: `argc` and `argv`. `argv` is an array on `char *`, where `argv[0]` is the name of  your program. The first argument of `execlp` is the actual program, and the rest is the values that are put into the `argv` array of the executed program. Read the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) a couple of times, and also experiment a little with the `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main`.

Comment: @user1109847 Extended my answer.

Comment: If i use execlp("cat", NULL) it works.. "i'm writing to the stdin and getting back the stdout"

Comment: Sorry, i tested it in another clean program, and it seems to work.