# Linux execlp in C++

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

It is my first time with Linux, and I need to use this

```
execlp("/usr/bin/wget", "wget", <URL STRING1>, NULL) system call in C++ code,
```

I cannot find anywhere how it should be written in C++, need some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819135/execlp-multiple-programs

Answer (score 1):

```
execl("/usr/bin/wget","wget","http://stackoverflow.com/",NULL);
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Include the `unistd.h`

```
#include <unistd.h> 

int main() {
    execlp("/usr/bin/wget", "wget", "http://www.google.com", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```