# Cannot execute binary file via execlp

Tags: c, linux

I am not able to execute a binary via [execlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819135/execlp-multiple-programs).

```
chdir("/home/foo/bar/baz/MB/");
execlp("bash", "bash", "./foobarbaz 1", NULL);
```

foobarbaz is my `c` file and I get the following error:

```
./foobarbaz: cannot execute binary file
```

I tried doing `chmod +x foobarbaz.c`

and also `test.c` the file in which `execlp` is present.

What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: "foobarbaz is my c file" really? do you mean it is your compiled executable or is it actually a source code file?

Comment: the extension is `.c`

Comment: In bash, can you `cd /home/foo/bar/baz/MB/` and `./foobarbaz 1`?

Comment: yes. In bash i can do that directly. @johnathan was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the binary directly:

```
execlp("./foobarbaz", "./foobarbaz", "1", (char *)0);
```

The shell is used to execute shell scripts (at least when you say `bash ./foobarbaz 1`); your binary isn't a shell script.

Comment: Just a question to add to that:
Does it mean, that the shell is not returned till the execution is done?

Comment: When you use `execlp()`, there is no shell involved; the process (your `./foobarbaz` program) replaces the current program and the process terminates when `./foobarbaz` exits.  If you had invoked it via the shell (`bash`, say), you might have written: `execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "./foobarbaz 1", (char *)0);` and then the shell you launched would in turn launch `./foobarbaz`, and the shell would wait for `./foobarbaz` to complete before exiting itself.  But it would mean that `bash` had replaced the current process instead of `./foobarbaz`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a C file - like foo.c you get an output binary

```
cc foo.c
```

gives ./a.out as the binary file

```
cc foo.c -o foo
```

gives ./foo as the binary file

foo.c is not executable.

Comment: I did it give it as `./foo 1` and not `foo.c 1` , right? why is it still an error?